# Chrome Extension chrome.storage.sync.get() returns empty object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I have following code to store some string value in storage:

```
function setData(dat) {
chrome.storage.sync.set({'key': dat}, function() {});
 }

function getData() {
chrome.storage.sync.get('key', function (obj) {
    alert('Your code is: ' + obj);
  });
}
```

And following usage of this code in my content script:

```
alert('processing');
setData('someVal');
getData();
```

But "getData" function always returns "object Object" instead of "someVal". What exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: chrome API is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) so you need to get the value in `set` callback.

Comment: Apart from the asynchronous tip from @wOxxOm, change `alert ('Your code is: ' + obj)` by `alert ('Your code is: ' + obj.key)`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko , thank's It works for me

Comment: Related/duplicates: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) and [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)